# why will a dl tag without a dt tag validate

Tags: html, validation, w3c

I've recently come across a website that makes use of definition list tags, albeit using them incorrectly, but still. they used them without declaring  a definition title as the first child of the definition list.

out of curiosity i put the following through the w3c validator

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <dl>
        <dd>description</dd>
        <dd>description</dd>
        <dd>description</dd>
    </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does this validate? surely it doesn't make a lick of sense semantically? or am i just missing something completely and utterly obvious?

Comment: The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) has an excerpt from the DTD on the content model of the `dl` element. All it says there is that a `dl` can have `dt` and/or `dd` children and must not be empty. Since HTML 4 validation simply involves checking if the document conforms to the DTD, that's what makes it validate. Validation doesn't check the semantics of a document unless those semantics are codified in the DTD.

Comment: @BoltClock, you seem to have expanded the comment to an answer and then deleted it – I can’t see why. It is a fairly accurate answer.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: I wasn't sure if I was answering the question fully by simply saying that the only reason it validates is because it conforms to the DTD. But on second thought, you're right - I'll reinstate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary purpose of markup validation is to check the syntax of your markup, as well as the structure of certain specific element types and attributes to some extent. It doesn't evaluate the semantics of your markup.

For a language like HTML 4, which makes use of a DTD for validation, the only thing that is checked is that the markup conforms to that DTD, and you can only go so far into speccing semantics into a DTD. For example, as long as you mark up a table correctly, it doesn't matter whether you're using it for layout or for tabular data, it would still validate, because you can't tell using a DTD alone how that table is being used even if it's marked up correctly.

In this case, the only thing the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) and the DTD<sup>1</sup> say about a `dl` element is that it can have either `dt` or `dd` children (or both), and must not be empty:

```
<!-- definition lists - DT for term, DD for its definition -->

<!ELEMENT DL - - (DT|DD)+              -- definition list -->
<!ATTLIST DL
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  >
```

Even the HTML 4.01 specification doesn't elaborate on the various possible content models of a `dl`. It doesn't say whether it *makes sense* to have a list of `dd` elements without associated `dt` content or that it is required to associate your `dd` elements with at least one `dt` element.

[HTML5 does](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), however, state quite tersely that

> If a `dl` element has one or more `dd` element children but no `dt` element children, then it consists of one group with values but no names.

Which would make it sort of like a `ul` in terms of function and semantics, so to speak. Of course, in that case you might as well use a `ul` instead, but either there is a subtle difference between an unnamed group of associated values and an unordered list of things, or the standards are just perfectly comfortable with the idea of a `dl` that only has `dd` children.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You might be wondering, why not just have the HTML 4 DTD require every `dl` to have at least one `dt` child (and optionally at least one `dd` to go with it)? Aside from the fact that this has been made irrelevant in the face of HTML5 which still allows it anyway, it's not something I can answer.</sub>

Comment: Regarding the footnote, there does not seem to be any explanation, so it is fair to assume that they just wanted to keep the syntax rules simple. A more logical approach would be more complicated, probably with the content model `(DT) (DT | DD)* (DD)`.

Comment: I'm facing a case here, where we have a `DL` dynamically build. And it makes sense to have a `dl`, because we have terms and their definition there. However, some of the `dd`, are quite generally speaking "obvious", so there's no need for adding those `dt` there. For example, you have `dd` as dates, that you understand that those are dates, and hence, no need to add a `dt` to say: "dates". (not sure if accessibility plays a role here). As far as I can tell, for this case, I'm just glad it is allowed to have, inside a `definition list` some elements without `definition terms`. What say you?

Comment: @MEM: Any dd that follows at least one dt will always be associated with that dt (the closest one). If your dl only contains one dd with a date, it's fine to keep it that way, but if it's dynamic, I'd recommend just always giving every dd a dt for the sake of simplicity.